# extract or slice specific associated array elements from a given array

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

How do I extract or slice specific associated array elements from a given array?

For instance, I am given array `array('k1'=>123, 'k2'=>'123', 'k3'=>'abc', 'k4'=>'123', 'k5'=>'', 'k6'=>NULL)` and want only elements k1, k3, and k6, how do I get `array('k1'=>123, 'k3'=>'abc', 'k6'=>NULL)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`array_intersect_key()`](http://php.net/array_intersect_key):

```
$keys = array('k1', 'k2', 'k6');
$result = array_intersect_key($array, array_flip($keys));
```

Output:

```
array(3) {
  ["k1"]=>
  int(123)
  ["k2"]=>
  string(3) "123"
  ["k6"]=>
  NULL
}
```

[**Demo.**](https://eval.in/83751)

Comment: Thanks.  I just came up with the same.  Unless I see something better, I will select this answer.